# PHP unable to write a variable to XML file

Tags: php, html, xml

I am unable to get my php code to write my $result variable into the XML file. It does write the $number1 variable that I just added for testing but it doesnt want to add the $result. I need this, so that I can make a memory and memory recall button for my calculator. This is for a school project and I have to use XML. Thanks.

```html
<?php

 $number1 = $_POST['number1'];
 $number2 = $_POST['number2'];;
 $operator = $_POST['operator'];
 
 if ($operator == 'subtract'){
 subtract();
 }
 
 if ($operator == 'add'){
 add();
 }
 
 if ($operator == 'multiply'){
 multiply();
 }
 
 if ($operator == 'divide'){
 divide();
 }
 
 function add() {
  global $number1;
  global $number2;
  
  $result = $number1 + $number2;
  echo $result;
 }
 function subtract() {
  global $number1;
  global $number2;
  
  $result = $number1-$number2; 
  echo $result;
 }
 function multiply() {
  global $number1;
  global $number2;
  
  $result = $number1*$number2; 
  echo $result;
 }
 function divide() {
  global $number1;
  global $number2;
  
  $result = $number1/$number2;
  echo $result;
 }
 
$handle = fopen('Data.xml', 'w');

fwrite($handle, "<inputs>\n\t<input>\n\t\t<answer>".$result."</answer>\n\t\t<number1>".$number1."</number1>\n\t</input>\n</inputs>");

fclose($handle);



echo "Write to input.xml successfully";
 
?>

<html>
 <center> 
 <h1 style="color:blue;">Rohit's Math Machine</h1> 
  <form action="Code.php" method="POST">
  Enter Number 1: <input type="text" name="number1" method="POST"><br><br>
  
     <select name="operator" method="POST">
     
     <option value="subtract">subtract</option>
     <option value="add">add</option>
     <option value="multiply">multiply</option>
     <option value="divide">divide</option>
     
    </select><br><br>
    
  Enter Number 2: <input type="text" name="number2" method="POST"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form> 
 </center>

</html>
```

Comment: `$result` does not exist at the global level, it only exists within some functions. by adding `global $result;` at the top of those functions you can make that variable global. It's not pretty, but it will 'work'.

Comment: Hi, this elimated the error messages but it still doesnt print the $result. It says writing to xml succesful but writes nothing. Do i have to change something in the functions?

Comment: NVM got it working by adding global $result inside the functions too. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Such a calculator would be ideal to learn about classes. You can then use properties of the calculator class instead of using global variables.

Comment: Do you have any resources that can help me with classes. I just find coding with classes very confusing because of the $this and other stuff I dont really get.

Comment: If you don't get classes then the best thing to do to get a book or follow a course. It's basic stuff covered in almost all books and courses about PHP. The problem might be: You have to put in some effort.